# How to insert json values into object

Tags: javascript, json

I have a predefined object (`SampleObject`) like this:

```
{
   ID: "", 
   Name: "", 
   URL: "", 
   prevName: "",
   Code: "",
}
```

And I want to insert the below json object values(values only):

```
var object =
{
"Sample" : {
    "Data" : {
        "ID" : "12345",
        "Name" : "SampleName: Name",
        "URL" : "www.google.com",
        "prevName" : "phones",
        "Code" : "USD"
    } 
}
```

into the above predefined object. How do I do that?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want the keys carried over? JSON relies on key/value pairs.

Comment: What do you mean by "insert"? You can just take `pageObject.page.pageInfo` in that case, can't you?

Comment: Or do you want to merge them?

Comment: *I want to insert the below json object values*, that's not a "JSON object", it's just an ordinary javascript object.

Comment: It seems to me that the first prefedined object and the JSON do not have matching properties.. everything is sort of randomized as far as I can tell. You could create a loop and compare the keys, and if they match then set the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a `for in` loop and set the value checking if the key is present in the object or not.

Check if the property is present on the emptyObject, and then copy that over to it.

```
for (var key in pageInfo) {
  var value = pageInfo[key];

  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    obj[key] = value;
  }
}
```

**[Code Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/reWVpY)**

Answer (score 1):

It is an object. There is no reason to use push or another method.

Simply take your defined object `pageObject.page` and assign a new key value pair with literal syntax.

```
pageObject.page['pageInfo'] = predefinedObject
```

or in more common syntax

```
pageObject.page.pageInfo = predefinedObject
```

Comment: I tried this `pageObject.page.pageInfo = pageObject;` and printing it to console prints empty values

Comment: Your values on your sample object are all empty, is that the reason why? I am certain this is possible in JavaScript

Comment: the values are there `"pageName" : "smartphones:samsung-galaxy-s-5",`

Comment: If you directly referenced it like you mentioned in your first comment, make sure you're console logging the correct key/value pair of the object. Log the entire object to be sure and go through all of its k/v pairs. If you are unable to make the page object the same format and directly assign it, I recommend doing what @Sushanth -- put down. It does what you're looking for. Don't forget to accept his/her answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code below the JSON Object

```
var digitalData= {page:{pageInfo:''}};
digitalData.page.pageInfo = pageObject.page.pageInfo;
console.log(digitalData.page.pageInfo);
```